# OpenGL samples for use with ArcEngine? Inspired by video I linked in post

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine

Inspired by this video: http://www.youtube.com/user/mresri#p/a/u/0/KjcDWG8nV1g

What are some good OpenGL resources for use with ArcEngine? 
C# ArcEngine 10

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any 3D stuff so did not know the answer to this, but I did some research:

The sample in the video is based on [ArcGIS Explorer](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgis-explorer/1500/about) and in ArcGIS Explorer 500 it seems to be possible to do [custom drawing](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/explorer/CustomDrawing.html) using OpenGL. But in later versions it has  been removed according to this [forum post](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=184&f=2208&t=288791&mc=4) and this [forum post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/4501-OpenGL-Drawing-in-build-1200). The way suggested to do this in ArcGIS Explorer is to use [graphics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/1500/sdk/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_add_graphics/000200000057000000/) to do custom drawing.

[ArcGIS Engine](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgis-engine/10.0/about) has nothing to do with ArcGIS Explorer, Engine is based on ArcObjects (COM) and Explorer has it's own objects and SDK (.Net), so checking out the concepts in the documentation for Engine brings up the following sample [How to draw a bitmap element using OpenGL](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000016q000000).